# Echo a specific values of a json

Tags: json

Currently working with this sort of json:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Ramones",
        "authors": {
            "6172": {
                "lastname": "Ramone",
                "firstname": "Joey",
            },
            "6768": {
                "lastname": "Ramone",
                "firstname": "Dee Dee",
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And would like to display values as this:

> **Ramones**
>  Joey Ramone
>  Dee Dee Ramone

The PHP code i use:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("my-json-url"),true);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo "<h1>".$item['title']."</h1>";
    echo .$item['authors']['firstname'].$item['authors']['lastname'];
};
```

And as result i only get the title value, didn't know how to pass through the ID number.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second foreach loop to loop through the authors of your item :

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("my-json-url"),true);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo "<h1>".$item['title']."</h1>";
    foreach($item['authors'] as $author)
        {
        echo "\n".$author['firstname']." ".$author['lastname'];
        }
};
```

I also improved the authors output, so you get the wanted display.